# Debugging does not work properly for WP8 apps in Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2015

Hi I have installed Visual studio 2015 preview and trying to debug one of my WP8 apps. I put a break point and during the debugging it hits the breakpoint but it gives and error:

> Internal error in the expression evaluator

when I try to look a value of local/global variable. Also stack trace shows as

> XYZ.DLL!

instead of real function names. I have tried turning on/off "Use managed compatibility mode" but it didn't fix the issue.

Attaching screenshot:

[image]

EDIT: It works fine with Windows Phone 8.1 OS.

Comment: are the symbols loaded for the external dll?

Comment: Yes it is loaded. Myadrotator.dll is my dll.

'TaskHost.exe' (CoreCLR: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{4C4D6250-230E-4CC5-A05B-8000E5776CE9}\Install\MyadRotator.DLL'. Symbols loaded.

Comment: VS2015 is `a PREVIEW`, hence the name. It's meant just for evaluation, not for production use. All you can do is to submit a bug to Microsoft, but I doubt anyone will solve alpha/beta software problems here.

Comment: While @walther is right, you could try restarting the VS, that will fix most of the problems;)

Comment: Also I'm surprized that you're using `Interlocked.Exchange` with UI elements? Are you accessing UI in multiple threads?

Comment: I have tried rebooting several times as I do with all other software/hardware systems without any luck :)